# Powershell schedule task using schtasks.exe returns error success is not recognized

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule another powershell script using `schtasks.exe` using following command:

```
$Command = cmd /c "$Env:WinDir/system32/schtasks.exe /create /s $ComputerName  /tn $TaskName /tr $TaskRun /sc $Schedule /d $Days /st $StartTime /RU system"

Invoke-Expression $Command
```

It schedules the task on remote servers but throws an error:

> "The term 'SUCCESS:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

It does successfully schedule the job at correct times but throws this error.
Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Thank you Erwin for editing it and making it easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is displayed because when you create your `$command` variable, your setting it's value to the RESULT of the expression, which is `SUCCESS`. The command is done running before your execute `Invoke-Expression`. Because of that, `Invoke-Expression` is actually running the result (`SUCCESS`) as it's scriptblock, and you get an error. Proof:

```
PS > $command = whoami

PS > $command
computer\user

PS > $command = 'whoami'

PS > $command
whoami
```

You can either just call the command directly as you do when you create your `$command` variable, or you can save the expression(`cmd /c ...`) as a string and then invoke it. Ex:

```
$Command = 'cmd /c "$Env:WinDir/system32/schtasks.exe /create /s $ComputerName  /tn $TaskName /tr $TaskRun /sc $Schedule /d $Days /st $StartTime /RU system"'

Invoke-Expression $Command
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me in detail what is going on. It worked perfectly.